# How to display AVG(AGE) using subquery?

Tags: mysql

I  have to display Mothers_name, AGE and Average age from the table below using a subquery?

I tried

```
SELECT Mothers_name,
       Age,
       AVG(Age)
FROM   MOTHERS
WHERE  Age > (SELECT AVG(Age)
              FROM   MOTHERS)
```

but this doesn't display Average age.

```
+-----------+--------------+-----+------+
| MothersID | Mothers_name | Age | KIDS |
+-----------+--------------+-----+------+
|        41 | Kirke        |  19 |    1 |
|        44 | Kiisu        |  19 |    1 |
|        26 | Mormela      |  20 |    2 |
|        45 | Merka        |  20 |    1 |
|        19 | Zandra       |  20 |    1 |
|        24 | Kiisuke      |  20 |    1 |
|        18 | Kristlin     |  21 |    1 |
|         1 | Imbi         |  21 |    1 |
|        10 | Kiki         |  22 |    1 |
|         8 | Lilleke      |  22 |    3 |
|        29 | Silja        |  22 |    1 |
|        17 | Plikake      |  23 |    1 |
|        36 | Fly          |  24 |    2 |
|        37 | Blanka       |  24 |    1 |
|        16 | Moonika      |  24 |    1 |
|        20 | Pisikeingel  |  24 |    1 |
|        27 | Krista       |  24 |    2 |
|        32 | Margariita   |  24 |    2 |
|        13 | Signeke      |  25 |    1 |
|        40 | Mari         |  25 |    1 |
|        47 | Maiki        |  26 |    1 |
|        31 | Liisa-Lota   |  26 |    1 |
|         2 | Rapunzel     |  26 |    2 |
|        46 | Pille        |  26 |    1 |
|        14 | Eveke        |  26 |    2 |
|        21 | Jessika      |  27 |    1 |
|        48 | Lilleke      |  27 |    2 |
|        15 | Nadja        |  27 |    2 |
|        23 | Triinu       |  27 |    2 |
|        33 | Annika       |  27 |    1 |
|        35 | Nella        |  28 |    2 |
|         6 | Miili        |  28 |    1 |
|        34 | Piibe        |  28 |    2 |
|        11 | Katriin      |  28 |    2 |
|         5 | Kurr         |  28 |    1 |
|        22 | Kriste       |  28 |    3 |
|         4 | Kristall     |  29 |    1 |
|        38 | Roosi        |  29 |    2 |
|        39 | Ave          |  29 |    3 |
|        50 | Katrin       |  29 |    2 |
|        12 | Zipsik       |  29 |    1 |
|        43 | Tups         |  30 |    1 |
|         3 | Katariina    |  30 |    1 |
|        28 | Carmen       |  30 |    2 |
|        49 | Viki         |  30 |    2 |
|        30 | Viivi        |  31 |    1 |
|         7 | Patsike      |  31 |    3 |
|        42 | Marja        |  32 |    1 |
|         9 | Margareth    |  32 |    2 |
|        25 | Ade          |  34 |    2 |
+-----------+--------------+-----+------+
```

Comment: Please share the code you've tried to solve the problem

Comment: SELECT Mothers_name,Age,AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS WHERE Age > (Select AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS)

Comment: That's clearly a different query. Try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Mothers_name, Age,
   (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS) as total_avg
FROM MOTHERS) as tmp WHERE age > total_avg
```

Comment: Thankyou thats what i was looking for :)

Comment: SELECT Mothers_name,
       Age,
       (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS) as Average_age
FROM   MOTHERS
WHERE  Age > (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS) - Got the same result with this, but thanks the answer you gave me was the one i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the average age of mothers that have the same name, you should group by the name field:

```
SELECT Mothers_name, Age, AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS 
WHERE Age > (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS) 
GROUP BY Mothers_name;
```

The problem is, I'm not seeing any duplicates in the dataset. If that is the case, the age and average age will be the same value. Can you clarify what results you are expecting?

Comment: No i dont need to group anything, I just need a table that displays Mothers that are older than AVERAGE and the table should contain THEIR NAME, AGE, AVERAGE AGE.

Comment: Then you can try:

Comment: `SELECT Monthers_name, Age, (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM MOTHERS) AS 'avg_age'`